# windows security

Tags: windows, security

Good day

Im trying to implement a read/write privilege in a folder but no delete rights in windows server 2003. Does anyone knows how to set this kind of security? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Change" permission is "RXWD" (read, execute, write, delete).
So if you remove the Delete right for that user it should work. Make sure you apply this permission to the folder, subfolders and all files. Also verify effective permissions for that this user (e.g. that this user is not part of some other group where he/she may get extra unwanted permissions)

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be to use "[DACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717798(VS.85).aspx)"s.

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried the "Advanced" button?

Comment: Yes, I've already added a special persmission for a certain user and unchecked "Delete Subfolder and Files" and "Delete" checkbox, but still the user do have delete access..

Comment: check if this user is part of another group where he/she gets this "delete" permission from.